# How to submit form method get with mod_rewrite url?

Tags: php, html, forms, apache, mod-rewrite

How to submit form method `get` with `mod_rewrite` url ?

this is my code

```
<form method="GET" action="https://www.example.com/search/">
    <input type="text" name="search" value="" placeholder="search">
    <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

When i submit form. It's will be redirect to

```
https://www.example.com/search/?search=test
```

How can i apply my code for redirect to

```
https://www.example.com/search/test/1
```

after submit form ?

Comment: _Method 1_: Use `POST` instead of `GET`; _Method 2_: Use javascript/jquery to submit the form, where you can build your url from form elements

Answer (score 0):

Your backend should set `Location` header:

```
Location: https://your.domain/search/test/1
```

[The code](http://www.webconfs.com/154/301-redirects-how-to-redirect-your-website/):

```
$ cat search/index.html
<form method="GET" action="https://your.domain/search/post.php">
    <input type="text" name="search" value="" placeholder="search">
    <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>


$ cat search/post.php
<?php
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: https://your.domain/search/test.html");
    exit();
?> 

$ cat search/test.html
Redirection works fine
```

To decide dynamically where to redirect you should check `$POST[ ]` hash.

Comment: Yes, and you additionally should check if you have no `POST/GET` data you show your form else redirect.

Comment: i don't understand could you please give me some sample code ?

Comment: this is php ? what it's mean for `$ cat search/post.php` ?

Comment: @RobertDown That is three different files. [`cat`](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=cat&category=8&russian=0) is unix command; `$` is shell promt